# Define Dependent Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly-dash, key-value, dashboard

I am working on an NLP project analyzing the words spoken by characters in The Office.  Part of this project involves making a network diagram of which characters talk to each other for a given episode.

This will be shown in a Dash app by allowing a user to select dropdowns for 4 parameters: season, episode, character1, and character2.

Here is a relevant snippet of my code so far:

```
#Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


#Load data
sheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wS5AAwOh8QO95RwHLS95POmSNKA2jjzdt0phrxeAE0/edit#gid=747974534'
url = sheet_url.replace('/edit#gid=', '/export?format=csv&gid=')
df = pd.read_csv(url)

#Set parameters
choose_season = df['season'].unique()
choose_episode = df['episode'].unique()
choose_character = ['Andy','Angela', 'Darryl', 'Dwight', 'Jan', 'Jim','Kelly','Kevin','Meredith','Michael','Oscar','Pam','Phyllis','Roy','Ryan','Stanley','Toby']

#Define app layout
app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown1',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in choose_season],
                value=choose_season[0]
            ), width=3
        ),
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown2',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in choose_episode],
                value=choose_episode[0]
            ), width=3
        ),
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown3',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in choose_character],
                value=choose_character[0]
            ), width=3
        ),
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='dropdown4',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in choose_character],
                value=choose_character[1]
            ), width=3
        )

    ])
])

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

In order to have this work efficiently, I would like to have the following dependencies in the dropdown menus:

1.) The selection of the first dropdown menu updates the dropdown menu
ie: Season updates possible episodes

2.) The selection of the first two dropdown menus updates the 3rd and 4th dropdown menus
ie: Season, Episode updates possible characters (if a character was not in that episode, they will not appear)

3.) The selection of the third dropdown menu updates the fourth dropdown menu
ie: If a character is selected in the third dropdown menu, they can not be selected in the fourth (can't select the same character twice)

I understand one way to do this is to make a massive season to episode dictionary and then an even larger season to episode to character dictionary.

I've already made the code to process the season to episode dictionary:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('dropdown2', 'options'), #--> filter episodes
    Output('dropdown2', 'value'),
    Input('dropdown1', 'value') #--> choose season
)
def set_episode_options(selected_season):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in season_episode_dict[selected_season]], season_episode_dict[selected_season][0]
```

I can definitely build these dictionaries, but this seems like a really inefficient use of time.  Does anyone know of a way to build these dictionaries with just a few lines of code?  Not sure how to approach building these in the easiest way possible.  Also, if you have an idea for a better way to approach this problem, please let me know that too.

Comment: You have a spreadsheet with all the data already, and you've converted it into a pandas data frame. I'd say forget the dictionary, and just use the data frame. You can filter it based on season or episode and easily extract the data you need without ever having to build a dictionary.

Comment: Hey @coralvanda!  Thanks for the response.  I'm not sure if that would work since I want to have the dropdown options to be dependent on parent dropdowns and I would have to define those options outside of the callback.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to set up a season-episode-character dictionary that can be called on like in that example callback I have listed without making a massive dictionary by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're asking about now. Something like this should get you a basic dictionary, which you could then modify for the `options` param for the dropdowns.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(url)
season_episode_character_dictionary = {}

for season in df['season'].unique.tolist():
    df_season = df[df['season'].eq(season)]
    season_episode_character_dictionary[season] = {}

    for episode in df_season['episode'].unique.tolist():
        df_episode = df_season[df_season['episode'].eq(episode)]
        characters = df_episode['characters'].unique.tolist()
        season_episode_character_dictionary[season][episode] = characters
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Just had to add on the () on the end of unique